# Select rows with multiple values in column SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataframe which i want to group by specific columns and then **select only rows with multiple values (> 1) in colum** FieldID_distinct. Goal is to find distinct FieldID with same DateTime, SerialNumber, geometry, FarmName, FieldName.

My query

```
select DateTime, SerialNumber, geometry, FarmName, FieldName,
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT FieldID) AS FieldID_distinct
from `xxx.yyy.zzz`
group by 1,2,3,4,5
order by DateTime ASC
```

I tried

```
where FieldID_distinct> 2
```

and

```
having FieldID_distinct> 2
```

but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just count the values in a `having` clause:

```
select DateTime, SerialNumber, geometry, FarmName, FieldName,
       ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT FieldID) AS FieldID_distinct
from `xxx.yyy.zzz`
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
having count(distinct FieldID) > 2
order by DateTime ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

for Oracle you have to make use of count() function
 having count(FieldID_duplicate) >2 .

Comment: the message i got: Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed at [6:14]

Comment: Can u try, having count (*) > 2 . Include count(*) in select clause also.                                PS : I think star is not visible in comments.

Comment: having count (ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT FieldID) AS FieldID_distinct) > 1, returns me Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword AS at [2:43]

Comment: Count(*) .. this way

Comment: I am even more confused now...can you please be more accurate or maybe answer with the whole syntax in the answer? Thank you!

Comment: select DateTime, SerialNumber, geometry, FarmName, FieldName, DISTINCT FieldID, count(FieldID) 
from `xxx.yyy.zzz`
group by 1,2,3,4,5
order by DateTime ASC  having count (FieldID) >1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216050/discussion-between-sauribabu-and-kuki).